# How to change font in HTML5?

Tags: html, text

I want the text on my project to look clean. I have tried this:

```
<p font-family="Roboto>Hi</p>
```

but that didn't work. Have any of you got any solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've missed end quote and forgot about invoke style inline.

```
<p style="font-family: 'Roboto';">Hi</p>
```

But this is very bad practice. Enable your font in css. It would be better and correct only.

Comment: your syntax is wrong in the style attribute; it needs to be `<p style="font-family: 'Roboto';">Hi</p>`. Your example will not work as-is.

Comment: Semicolon makes sense, but doesn't matter generally. Anyway, doesn't make sense to use styles inline. Corrected, thx.

Comment: Thanks! The feedback helped.

Comment: @IvanKharkovsky it's not just the semicolumn, the `=` is also invalid, check my line of code in the previous comment (I fixed it for you, it's completely valid now).